# How to determine all centralizers in $A_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that the order of a conjugacy class of $A_5$ is $1,12,15$ or
> $20$.

There are $4$ different cycle type in $A_5$. There are $20$ permutations of cycle type $(123)$, $24$ permutations of cycle type $(12345)$ and $15$ permutations of cycle type $(12)(34)$.

As this is an exercise of the Sylow chapter, I think I need to use it somewhere, but I don't see how. I would say that the centralizers are calculated like:

$C(123)=3$, as I think only $\langle (123) \rangle$ commutes.
$C(12)(34)= 4$, as I think only $\langle \{(12),(34) \} \rangle$ commutes.
$C(12345)=5$, as I think only $\langle (12345) \rangle$ commutes.

But I don't know how to prove these statements more rigoursly. Is there some kind of theorem to determine the centralizer ?

We know that all elements in a conjugacy class must have the same cycle type. It seems like that the converse is not true for $A_5$. $60/C(12345)=60/5=12$ while there are $24$ permutations of this type. For the other cycle types, the conjugacy class doesn't split up. It follows that the order of the conjugacy classes are $60/5=12,\;60/4=15,\;60/3=20$ and $60/60=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that the permutation $g$ commutes with $(1,2,3)$. By the rule for conjugating permutations, we have $(1,2,3) = g(1,2,3)g^{-1} = (g(1),g(2),g(3))$.

Now an $n$-cycle can be expressed as a cycle in $n$ different ways. In the case $n=3$, we have $(1,2,3)=(2,3,1)=(3,1,2)$. So there are three possibilities for
$g(1),g(2),g(3): 1,2,3;$ $2,3,1;$ or $3,1,2$. Note that we could also have $g(4),g(5) = 4,5$ or $5,4$, but the only $g$ with $g(4)=5$, $g(5)=4$ are odd permutations, so there are just three possible $g$ in $A_5$: identity, $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,1,2)$.

You can calculate the centralizers of $(1,2)(3,4)$ and $(1,2,3,4,5)$ using similar arguments.

Yes, you are right, there are two classes of 5-cycles in $A_5$. $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $(1,2,3,5,4)$ are conjugate in $S_5$ but not in $A_5$.

Answer (score 1):

> $C(123)=3$, as I think only $\langle (123) \rangle$ commutes.
> $C(12)(34)= 4$, as I think only $\langle \{(12),(34) \} \rangle$ commutes
> $C(12345)=5$, as I think only $\langle (12345) \rangle$ commutes

Since @Derek Holt has demonstrated the case for $C(123)$, another approach is to use Obit-Stablizer-Theorem. We use $C(12)(34)$ as an example. First, we consider everything in $S_5$,

$$|C_{S_5}(12)(34)|=\frac{|S_5|}{|cl_{S_5}(12)(34)|}=\frac{5!}{|cl_{S_5}(12)(34)|}$$

where $|cl_{S_5}(12)(34)|$ is the number of elements in the conjugacy class of $(12)(34)$ in $S_5$, we know:

$$|cl_{S_5}(12)(34)|=\frac{5!}{2^2\cdot 2!\cdot 1^11!}=15$$

Plug in and we get:

$$|C_{S_5}(12)(34)|=8$$

Next, we move to $A_5$.
Since $cl_{S_5}(12)(34)$ do NOT split in $A_5$, we get

$$|cl_{A_5}(12)(34)|=|cl_{S_5}(12)(34)|=15$$

Again, we use Obit-Stablizer-Theorem,

$$|C_{A_5}(12)(34)|=\frac{|A_5|}{|cl_{A_5}(12)(34)|}=\frac{5!/2}{15}=4$$

Finally, let's list them and verify. Again, we consider it in $S_5$ first.

We want to find all $g\in S_5$, such that $g(1,2)(3,4)g^{-1}=(1,2)(3,4)$, we have

$$g(1,2)(3,4)g^{-1}=g(1,2)g^{-1}g(3,4)g^{-1}=(g(1), g(2))(g(3), g(4))=(1,2)(3,4)$$

Now, we have $8$ combinations to assign the value for $g$

$$\begin{align} g(1)&=1, g(2)=2, g(3)=3, g(4)=4\Longrightarrow g_1=(1)(2)(3)(4)=e\\
\\
g(1)&=2, g(2)=1, g(3)=3, g(4)=4\Longrightarrow g_2=(1, 2)(3)(4)=(1, 2)\\
\\
g(1)&=1, g(2)=2, g(3)=4, g(4)=3\Longrightarrow g_3=(1)(2)(3, 4)=(3, 4)\\
\\
g(1)&=2, g(2)=1, g(3)=4, g(4)=3\Longrightarrow g_4=(1, 2)(3, 4)\\
\\
g(1)&=3, g(2)=4, g(3)=1, g(4)=2\Longrightarrow g_5=(1, 3)(2, 4)\\
\\
g(1)&=4, g(2)=3, g(3)=1, g(4)=2\Longrightarrow g_6=(1,4,2,3)\\
\\
g(1)&=3, g(2)=4, g(3)=2, g(4)=1\Longrightarrow g_7=(1,3,2,4)\\
\\
g(1)&=4, g(2)=3, g(3)=2, g(4)=1\Longrightarrow g_8=(1,4)(2,3)\end{align}$$

There are totally $8$ elements in the subgroup $C_{S_5}(12)(34)=\{g_1,\dots,g_8 \}$. Next, we move to $A_5$, we can only select even permutations from above, hence

$$\boxed{C_{A_5}(12)(34)=\{g_1,g_4, g_5, g_8 \}}$$